# Duplicated content in Google after updating my URLs

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines, duplicate-content

I have a prestashop 1.6. Due a I had dirty URLs with ids, last week I bought [a module to clean those URLs](http://addons.prestashop.com/es/16633-pretty-urls.html).

A couple of days ago, I noticed a ranking drop in Google. I have checked Google Search console and I can see that all my products and categories are marked as duplicated, (old URL with ID and new one.)

After that, I have checked the old URLs have a 301 redirection, first visually and also using tools like http://www.seoreviewtools.com/redirect-checker-tool/ It seems all 301 redirections are OK.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 3):

A week isn't all that long (though I know it sure feels like it is). Steps you can take include:

1. Double/triple check your 301 redirects are pointing to the correct new URLs.
2. Ensure your sitemap.xml includes all of the new URLs and none of the old. [Resubmit the sitemap](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283) in Google Search Console.
3. Check your canonical tags include the new URLs.
4. Look at any external links you can find and have them updated to use the new URLs.

Other than that, have a lot of patience.

Comment: Andrew, do you think is it good idea to put rel canonical for the old product pages? (I mean the urls with id) or even send the old url to the robots.txt

Comment: If you 301 redirect the old URLs to the new URLs then there will be no canonical to be read on the old pages.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to manage this sort of search for content is:
(in the Google search bar) site:yoursitename.com and see what is indexed. 
Then remove your plug-in. Work manually for best results.

First: go to https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ or a similar site and get a sitemap.
Then EDIT it so that you have only the pages (new ones).

Next upload this and tell Google where the sitemap it via Google Webmaster Tools / Google Search Console.

Then read this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598466?authuser=0&rd=1

Once read MANUALLY ask Google to remove URLs